# 2 issues when getting Yahoo Finance historical data in Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

Currently I try to download the historical stock prices from Yahoo Finance for personal research purpose. But when I used Selenium in Python to download data, I encountered 2 issues:
1. It took too long time to fully download the web page because it has a lot of external links need to load. There was always a Loading Timeout exception.

2. When I used try and exception to deal with the timeout exception, but the button used to change the date doesn't work. I guess that this is caused by the web page hasn't been totally loaded.

I am a beginner to Python and Selenium, so could you please advise on this issue?

Comment: Can you sum up your manual steps which you are trying to Automate?

Answer (score 0):

Find below 3 methods:

Checking page readyState (not reliable):

```
def page_has_loaded(self):
    self.log.info("Checking if {} page is loaded.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    page_state = self.driver.execute_script('return document.readyState;')
    return page_state == 'complete'
```

Comparing new page ids with the old one:

```
def page_has_loaded2():
    self.log.info("Checking if {} page is loaded.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    try:
        new_page = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        return new_page.id != old_page.id
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

Using staleness_of method:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=10):
    self.log.debug("Waiting for page to load at {}.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    old_page = self.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
yield
WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

For more details, check [Harry's blog.](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I will try your suggestions and post the results here.